# REST Http 404 on redirect with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have an `RESTfull` service called by an external system (`GET`). After the service did the job the service should redirect to another external system (`URI`) like `http:\\example.com\success`.

But i always recieve an `http 404` `Error` at the client (browser) - without doing a redirect before.

I´m working with `Jersey 2.24, Tomcat 8, Java 8`

Here my code snippet:

```
    @Path("/serviceXY/v1_0/")
public class ServiceXYResource {

    @Path("success/sfp/mandants/{mandantnumber}/account/{accountnumber}")
    public Response successXY(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo, @NotNull @PathParam("mandantnumber") final String mandantnumber, @NotNull @PathParam("accountnumber") final String account) throws MyException
    {
        //read URL parameter
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
        URI targetURIForRedirection;
        try {
            String redirectURL = myService.doSomething(mandantnumber, accountnumber, queryParams);
            targetURIForRedirection = new URI(redirectURL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException | MyException exc) {
            logger.debug(exc);
            throw new MyException(exc);
        }
        return Response.seeOther(targetURIForRedirection).build();
    }  
}
```

I´m looking for a functioning solution. Could you help me?

The REST service using an extended exception mapper. 
This is the server side exception when jersey pocessing the build response:

```
2016-11-07 16:30:07,132 ERROR ThrowableMapper:52 - HTTP 404 Not Found
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:323)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: At first glance, this seems as though it would work fine...provided the redirect URL is to a resource that actually exists... In other words, your 404 has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: correct explanation